# How to set a range of different formulas to an Excel range from Delphi code?

Tags: vba, excel, delphi, automation

I try to set a range of different formulas, but it does not work via Delphi.

## VBA Test Code

To illustrate this, I have some VBA test-code that I can execute directly in Excel:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Formula = "=Complex(1, 1.2)"

    Dim vFormula(1 To 2) As Variant
    vFormula(1) = "=Complex(0, 0.1)"
    vFormula(2) = "=Complex(1, 1.2)"

    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Formula = vFormula
End Sub
```

and it works as expected:

[image]

Notes:

- cell `A1` contains a single formula
- cells `A2`, `B2` have been set with one call using a variant array of strings
- also note, that the Excel installation is in German and that the English formula `Complex` is shown in German `KOMPLEXE` in the screenshot - sweet

## Delphi Test Code

Now I try to do the same via Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddRangeFormulasClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  VarArr: Variant;
begin
  FWorksheet.Range['A1', 'A1'].Formula := '=Complex(1, 1.2)';

  VarArr := VarArrayCreate([0, 1], varOleStr);
  VarArrayPut(VarArr, '=Complex(0, 0.1)', [0]);
  VarArrayPut(VarArr, '=Complex(1, 1.2)', [1]);

  FWorksheet.Range['A2', 'B2'].Formula := VarArr;
end;
```

But this does not work as expected:

[image]

Notes:

- the single formula in `A1` works as expected
- but the variant array that I have set to `A2`, `B2` has not been converted

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit English locale
- Excel 2007 German
- Delphi 10.2

  - Excel TLB: Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library

## Update

Another try is to use the Locale dependant formula in Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddRangeFormulasGerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  VarArr: Variant;
begin
  FWorksheet.Range['A1', 'A1'].Formula := '=Komplexe(1, 1.2)';

  VarArr := VarArrayCreate([0, 1], varOleStr);
  VarArrayPut(VarArr, '=Komplexe(0, 0.1)', [0]);
  VarArrayPut(VarArr, '=Komplexe(1, 1.2)', [1]);

  FWorksheet.Range['A2', 'B2'].Formula := VarArr;
end;
```

this also does not work right away:

[image]

Notes:

- The formulas show up as unknown `#Name`
- But when I then enter each cell and exit again (without any changes) the data show up correctly (recalculation does not help) - which is not a big surprise, it is like directly entering the formulas in Excel
- Note, that it also does NOT work when I use `FormulaLocal` instead of `Formula`

Comment: It would be helpful to right that you are using Excel 2007 - German version, as it really matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must create a variant array of `varVariant` (instead of `varOleStr`) like this:

```
VarArrayCreate([0, 1], varVariant);
```

Then all my use-cases including the automatic formula translation work!

Thanks [@Vityata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448626/vityata)

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, `.Formula` takes the original English formula and it transfers it to Excel. Then, based on the local Excel installation, it is "translated". Thus, `=Complex()` becomes `=Komplexe()` in German.

Obviously in Delphi, this works in a similar way. `.Formula` translates correctly your English formula to German, thus `A1` is ok. The `VarArrayPut` probably takes `Text` and not `Formula`, thus it should be at the local language:

You can give it a try:

```
VarArrayPut(VarArr, '=Komplexe(0, 0.1)', [0]);
```

As a last resort, if you can find an English installation of Excel, your Delphi code should be working. To get some ideas about the Excel local formula's translation, this is how a standard `=IF()` formula gets translated:

- .Formula           `"=IF(B1=C1,""Equal"",""Not equal"")"`
- .FormulaR1C1       `"=IF(RC[1]=RC[2],""Equal"",""Not equal"")"`
- .FormulaLocal      `"=WENN(B1=C1,""Equal"",""Not equal"")"`
- .FormulaR1C1Local  `"=WENN(ZS(1)=ZS(2),""Equal"",""Not equal"")"`

[Source (disclaimer - my site)](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-formulas-in-excel-localformula/)

Comment: I also suppose that the data-types are somehow wrong. But on the other hand, also the formula of `A1` is a just a Delph String (there is no such thing as a `Formula`  type, AFAIK.

Comment: And of course I'd like to avoid locale specific formulas in my code - that would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @MartinTrummer - avoiding local specific is indeed a good idea. Concerning the new screenshot - why are you getting an English error and not a German one?

Comment: The German and English words for `Name` happen to be the same: see the [translation](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/name)

Comment: @Martin Trummer - yup, indeed 